# Google maps V3 search problems

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have been stuck at this problem for quite a while. I have a database with a little over 100 locations. And I am trying to write a page that will display the closest location to the user. Right now I am using PHP to display the locations in hidden fields and using Javascript to get and display the user location, and to get the distances from the user location(Distance Matrix). The problem I am running into is that I am getting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error after about 16 requests. I am getting the error from the distance matrix.

Comment: Don't forget that the query limit runs over 24h period ( 2.500 query/day)

Answer (score 1):

About the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` check the [Usage Limits on Distance Matrix API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#Limits), it sounds to 
me you're just going faster than 100 elements per 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this Store locator link for better understanding of Finding locations nearby with MySQL**

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way for php to detect the user location?

Comment: Yes ,,its possible by combining your lat ,lng data from database and XML,, and the distance query will fetch the nearby locations.